# How to track installs of mobile application with Facebook ADS in Windows Phone 8.1 C#

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

1. I've installed 'Facebook SDK for Windows & Windows Phone' v. 6.0.10.0 from Outercurve foundation through NuGet and followed steps in docs: http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/config/
2. App is registered on Facebook (although when I run https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/ it tells me 'You haven't set up any mobile app platforms for this app. You can add supported platforms in your App Settings.').
3. I've added platform 'Windows App' and filled in the 'Windows Store SID'

Now I just don't know what to do next. How do I track installs? Can't find anything in the docs here http://facebooksdk.net/docs/ regarding tracking of installs... I do not care about facebook login and all the samples seem to focus on using the authentication and then using the user's account.

Comment: You say you don't care about Facebook login - do you care about the ads? If you only care about installs, you shouldn't need the Facebook SDK.

Comment: I need to track the installs via Facebook API - AFAIK those are tracked via events and those are from ads part of the API...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/measuring/installs-and-in-app-conversions?locale=de_DE

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to achieve is not possible.
Facebook does not consider Windows (Phone) Applications as Mobile Applications.

As you can see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/resources/faqs there are several references to "Apple App Store" and "Google Play URL". That is the fact why you continuously get `You haven't set up any mobile app platforms for this app. You can add supported platforms in your App Settings.`. If you try to add an iOS or Android app with dummy data, you'll see this will show up. There is not one single reference to Windows Applications.

In this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/sdk#step-by-step
If you look in step 4, you'll get instructions only for iOS and Android.
There is also this remark in this point: `Desktop Canvas Apps: By integrating Facebook Login to your Facebook Canvas, App Launches and App Installs are logged automatically. Other Web Apps: We do not support install tracking for web apps not hosted on facebook.com.`

You could try to find a workaround, even changing the 'Facebook SDK for Windows & Windows Phone' v.6.0.10.0 from Outercurve somehow, but this feature seems to be connected directly to the respective stores, and this is probably why it is not yet possible to workaround this in any way.

I also tried to contact Facebook on this issue, but by now (10 Feb) I still didn't get any response. I will however update my answer if I have any news from them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... not the one I was hoping for but what are you gonna do...

What I also considered:
1. Create new Android/iOS fb app (there is one for the Android version already, but this would be wp-fakish one)
2. Create a proxy on my pc and sniff out the request - it has to be some simple HTTP POST or something